# CodeIgniter - Hello World

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to PHP, CodeIgniter, and I am currently studying the tutorials of both. I'm trying to build a blog tutorial, and I'm receiving some errors. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Controller**:

```
<?php

class Blog extends Controller{
   function index()
   {
   $data['title'] = "My Blog Title";
   $data['heading'] = "My Blog Heading";
   $data['todo'] = array('clean house','eat lunch','call mom');

   $this->load->view('blog_view');
   }
}
?>
```

**View**:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?=$title?></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?=$heading?></h1>

<ol>

<?php foreach($todo as $item): ?>

<li><?=$item?></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

**Errors**:

```
Message: Undefined variable: heading
Filename: views/blog_view.php
Line Number: 6


Message: Undefined variable: todo
Filename: views/blog_view.php
Line Number: 10


Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: views/blog_view.php
Line Number: 10
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to pass your $data variable to the view:

$this->load->view('blog_view', $data);

Answer (score 0):

and if you having that message again (happens when defined in methods other than the index method). best idea (the way i resolved it) is to put "@" before that variable in your view file. and woala...